# jQuery Validate - Group Fields not working properly when grouping multiple fields

Tags: jquery-validate, grouping

The below code works but for DOB, it displays the error message after the first text box (DayOfBirth) instead of the third one (YearOfBirth).

```
$("form").validate({
rules: {
    DayOfBirth: { required: true },
    MonthOfBirth: { required: true },
    YearOfBirth: { required: true },
    SSN1: { required: true },
    SSN2: { required: true },
    SSN3: { required: true }
},
groups: {
    DateofBirth: "DayOfBirth MonthOfBirth YearOfBirth",
    SSN: "SSN1 SSN2 SSN3"
},
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
   if (element.attr("name") == "DayOfBirth" || element.attr("name") == "MonthOfBirth" || element.attr("name") == "YearOfBirth") 
    error.insertAfter("#YearOfBirth");
   else 
    error.insertAfter(element);
if (element.attr("name") == "SSN1" || element.attr("name") == "SSN2" || element.attr("name") == "SSN3") 
    error.insertAfter("#SSN3Text");
   else 
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change...

```
error.insertAfter("#YearOfBirth");
```

to...

```
form.find(".error").append(error);
```

and the error will display after the YearOfBirth.

Next time, perhaps the whole code with the HTML or a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demostration of your problem would help explain your question more clearly.

Comment: No, it doesn't even validate now. I tried $("#YearOfBirth").append(error); but it's also doing the same.

Comment: Can you please post your whole code on jsFiddle or add it to the question?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was able to fix it myself.

Comment: No worries. Glad you fixed it.